# Access to file from jar archive

Tags: java, jar, stream

I have `file.jar`

at the root of the file located `readme.txt`

I want to get acces to this file from my application.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the file,since it is not a file on your file system.

You have to read it as stream, like

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/readme.txt");
```

or read docs of [JarURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/jarclassloader.html)

**update:**

Paste your file in src and just write , `File f =new File("/readme.txt").`

It it gives you.

If not update your post with your file structure.

Comment: But it doesn't  work if this jar file is my application. I execute java file.jar

Comment: I have not found it there

Comment: can you pleas tell what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I wrote simple application. package it to jar. application uses resources(readme.txt)

Comment: Paste your file in src and just write , `File f =new File("/readme.txt")`.It it gives  you. If not update your post with your file structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("readme.txt");
```

Comment: It is not necessary to "First, you have to have the jar in the classpath." See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the jar file is not on the classpath, instead at any arbitrary location, you can read it as a `ZipInputStream` (or `jarInputStream`) and process the content. An example is shown here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/